# Generating a scaffold with existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to generate a scaffold to an object which already has table in the database, so i don't need to migrate and stuff, but the question is, when i am generating a scaffold, for example:

```
rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

do i still to specify those fields ? (title, description, etc'..) or those fields are only used for the migration part, so if i already have a table, i don't need to specify them ..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generator is reading the fields you supplied and is building all the views (including forms) based on the input. It does not read the current db schema, so yes, you have to supply all the attributes.

UPDATE:

Note that it wills still work without attributes, but it will generate empty views.